# div to touch left and right end of browser

Tags: html, css, css-float

how to move the defie div left and the sales order div right......
i gave float property but not working.....
i wanted one div to touch extremely left and another div to move to the right....
providing my code below.....

http://jsfiddle.net/zbyLy/3/embedded/result/

```
<div style="padding-left: 41px; padding-top: 10px; float:left;">
            <a class="" href="#">
              <img alt="change" class="defieLogo" src="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/defie_logo_only.png">
            </a>
            <p style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 0px;">47657 Lakeview Blvd, Fremont CA 94538</p>
            <p>Tel: 510-657-8981 <span style="padding-left: 18px;">wwww.abcdfg.com</span></p>
      </div>

      <div style="border: 1px solid red; width: 300px; float:left;">
        <p style="color: #14486b; font-size: 18px; font-family: arial; font-wieght: bold; ">Sales Order</p>
        <p style=>Customer No. ABC01</p>
        <p style=>sales Order No. 100001</p>
        <p style=>Est. Ship Date 2/24/2013</p>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="border: 1px solid red; width: 300px; float:right;">
```

**demo :http://jsfiddle.net/zbyLy/**